# Where is "AsDynamic()"?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I've seen use of a method called `AsDynamic()`. IIRC it was an extension method. The idea is that for any object you can call `myObject.AsDynamic()` and get a dynamic version of it.

Thing is, I just can't find the `AsDynamic()` method, despite much Googling. I'm assuming it's something actually have implemented themselves, and I'd like to do the same.

I'm using .NET 4 client profile, and am very confused. :)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect we're as confused as you.  What are you looking for beyond `dynamic myDynamic = myObject;`?

Comment: Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonvalue.asdynamic(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @gdoron Yes I read the question. If you have a better idea, post it.

Comment: @L.B. Already did... [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9711084/601179) =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I was right - it was something someone (Greg Young) had a specific implementation for. The details of the implementation were taken from David Ebbo's blog:

[Use C# 4.0 dynamic to drastically simplify your private reflection code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/01/18/use-c-4-0-dynamic-to-drastically-simplify-your-private-reflection-code.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can just assign the variable in a dynamic var

```
Foo foo = GetFooFromSommehere();
dynamic dyn = foo;
```

Or cast it:

```
Foo foo = GetFooFromSommehere();
var dyn = (dynamic) foo;
```

Why should there be `AsDynamic()` method?
The `ToList()` method actually does stuff instead of casting unlike with `dynamic`.

Comment: I don't think that you get the idea of the question. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700293/parsing-complex-json-without-reflected-objects/9700430#9700430) for example where  `AsDynamic` would be used

Comment: @L.B. That example doesn't do "AsDynamic" It parse a JSON to a dynamic object. Not what was asked here... I know that `dynamic` can be helpful, but not the `AsDynamic()` method!

Comment: @Guys, the questioner is referring to an extension to the `dynamic` paradigm that allows access to `private` members (which he doesn't really explain, and the very link he provides outright says is not encouraged, thus my vote to close as too localized). Both of you have a valid point, but there's no need to argue over this.

Comment: Actually it was an implementation used by Greg Young. All it did was take an object and return a `dynamic` that you could then use to call methods on without using reflection to get a `MethodInfo` to invoke on the original object. I had no requirement as such to find *private* members.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply assign something to a dynamic variable or cast it to dynamic, since it is not type safe afterwards the cast should always go thorugh.

If you want an extension method:

```
public static class DynamicExtension
{
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this T value)
    {
        return (dynamic)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing an extension method to all types that just does a simple cast sounds, let say weird for me.

Comment: @gdoron sure does, but it was requested so here it is :) and when you are specific tasks during reflection it sure makes it a hole lot easier in some scenarios. not safer though, but it is reflection after all..

Comment: AsDynamic is better suited name here since it is a mere cast. `To` implies a conversion to something else.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for probably is a library method implemented in 
ReflectionMagic

http://www.nuget.org/packages/ReflectionMagic/

https://github.com/davidebbo/ReflectionMagic